# Не работает [(ngModel)] в md-select(Angular Material)

Tags: angular2

Вывожу в компоненте

```
<md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedOne">
    <md-option *ngFor="let food of selected" [value]="food.value" select="true">
        {{food.viewValue}}
    </md-option>
 </md-select>
```

Браузер выдаёт ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В классе пишу:

```
selected: any = [
    {viewValue: "Элемент 1", value: "0"},
    {viewValue: "Элемент 2", value: "1"},
    {viewValue: "Элемент 3", value: "2"},
    {viewValue: "Элемент 4", value: "3"},
];
selectedOne: string = "0";
```

Делаю всё по доке [Material Angular](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)
Но всё равно не хочется ставить элемент по умолчанию. Кто знает в чём может быть причина?
**Angular cli** 4.3; **material** 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Директива [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) расположена в модуле `FormsModule` из `@angular/forms`.

Поэтому для ее использования нужно импортировать этот модуль в модуль где находит указанный компонент.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало)